# MySQL Show name instead of ID from other Table

Tags: mysql, sql, typescript

I have two tables, one is Server table the other one is Company table and I need to show all the credentials from the server table and the company name instead of ID.
I need to get all servers by the company ID and display all the servers of that company.
How to join them correctly to show the name instead of ID?

Server:
serverId
serverName
serverIp
companyId
status
serverCreationDate

Company:
companyId
CompanyName

Comment: You need to provide the details of both tables

Answer (score 1):

Selecting the data is different than displaying the data.

Your SQL will be pulling all data that you specified and from the looks of the above you would bind them on Company.companyId = Server.companyId

In viewing of the results if you don't want the companyId visible then just leave that column out of the select statement.

It's been years since I've done some sql but something like below

```
Select c.CompanyName, s.serverId, s.serverName, s.serverIp, s.status, s.serverCreationDate
From Company c, Server s
Where c.companyId = s.companyId
```